# SQL Merge Statement - How to handle one to many inserts?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Currently, this series of statements performs essentially a one-to-one insert in both parent and child tables. I am wondering if I can continue to use a merge statement approach to insert only one statement in the parent for when there are multiple child rows on the child table that share the same link data.

```
MERGE INTO ParentTable  PT
USING (SELECT field1, field2…
FROM   @TempParentData TMP 
INNER JOIN ThirdTable THR 
ON THR.linkdata = PT.linkdata 
WHERE THR.id = @ID) PT1  
ON 1=2  
WHEN not matched then  
INSERT  (field1, field2…
VALUES  (field1, field2
OUTPUT  PT1.LID   
INTO  @TempLinkData;

INSERT INTO ChildTable  (field1, field2…
SELECT field1, field2…
FROM   @TempParentData TMP 
INNER JOIN ThirdTable THR 
ON THR.linkdata = TMP.linkdata 
WHERE  THR.id = @ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform a GROUP BY on the ParentTable fields in the merge (ie in the USING subquery), and output those fields (along with any IDENTITY Primary Key) into a second temporary table with an OUTPUT clause and the *inserted* memory table.

Join this second temporary table to @TempParentData to obtain everything necessary to INSERT the child rows.